# laravel redis cache add string length to values

Tags: laravel, caching, redis, predis

I use laravel / redis for caching , I realized laravel adds some strings begining of my values , the number is string length.
somthing like this :
When I put ABC string in a key , the retrived value is this :

```
s:3:"ABC";
```

How should I solve this problem ?

Comment: How are you retrieving the value?

Comment: I need to retrive the value without laravel cache manager . I use predis for that. $predisClient->get('myKey');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in that the Laravel Cache Manager serializes the value that it stores so that it can store more complexed types such as arrays.

What you want to do is `unserialize` the value, see the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) for more details.

So with your predis call you would do the additonal step of unserialize

```
unserialize($predisClient->get('myKey'));
```

this way the value will be "ABC"

Update:

To take into account [Vladislav Rastrusny comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34219430/laravel-redis-cache-add-string-length-to-values/34221349?noredirect=1#comment56192500_34221349) if you are storing different types of value including numerics you'll want to do something like this instead

```
$value = $predisClient->get('myKey');
$result = is_numeric($value) ? $value : unserialize($value);
```

see the how Laravel handles this with the get method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php#L52).

Comment: Please note, that Laravel [does not](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.php#L94) serialize numeric values for the sake of performance.